# manipulate both rows and columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe that needs to be manipulated before I can use it for analysis. The dataframe consists of walking counters in the different columns with their hourly count per day in the rows. An example below:

```
Date/time       counter1   counter2  counter3
1/1/2016 8:00      0           2        8
1/1/2016 9:00      1           0        3
1/1/2016 10:00     5           15       1
```

I need to transform the dataframe to the following structure:

```
Date/time       counter_name       count
1/1/2016 8:00    counter 1           0 
1/1/2016 9:00    counter 1           1  
1/1/2016 10:00   counter 1           5
1/1/2016 8:00    counter 2           2
1/1/2016 9:00    counter 2           0
1/1/2016 10:00   counter 2           15
1/1/2016 8:00    counter 3           8
1/1/2016 9:00    counter 3           3
1/1/2016 10:00   counter 3           1
```

I tried switching the rows with the colums using the transpose function but then I'm still not where I need to be and my rows have names but my rows don't need to have names. Is there someone who can help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-"Date/time", names_to="counter_name", values_to="count")
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  `Date/time`    counter_name count
  <chr>          <chr>        <int>
1 1/1/2016 8:00  counter 1        0
2 1/1/2016 8:00  counter 2        2
3 1/1/2016 8:00  counter 3        8
4 1/1/2016 9:00  counter 1        1
5 1/1/2016 9:00  counter 2        0
6 1/1/2016 9:00  counter 3        3
7 1/1/2016 10:00 counter 1        5
8 1/1/2016 10:00 counter 2       15
9 1/1/2016 10:00 counter 3        1
```